# EditText with afterTextChanged to float and numeric format

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android project and I have to set EditText with 'mask'.

It's float format, but I have one little problem. I can't input 0 number (for example I would like to have 0,05 as result)

Now it's working like:

- typing 5000 give me result 5 000
- typing 1234 give me result 1 234
- typing 0123 give me result 1 23 but should 0 123

any help appreciated...

```
            final EditText editText =  new EditText(v.getContext());
            editText.setLayoutParams(params);
            editText.setText("");
            editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLenght)});
            editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                int len=0;

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    try {
                        String str = String.format("%,d", Long.parseLong(s.toString()
                                .replaceAll(",", "")));
                        String str = s.toString();
                        int pos = editText.getSelectionStart();

                        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                        editText.setText(str);
                        editText.setSelection(pos + str.length() - s.length());
                        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence c, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 

                }


            });
```

Comment: what actually is your goal ?

Comment: goal is to give possibility typing 0; now it's cutting 0;
"typing 0123 give me result 1 23 but should 0 123"